# bind9 slow performances than google dns

Tags: debian, bind

On debian 9 I configurated bind9 (v.9.10.3) as cache server, later as forwarders server. For testing purpose I don't have any firewall and I make test from internal lan gigabit. Bind works but performances are not so good, for example:

```
dig aruba.it @192.168.50.35 (my BIND)
Query time: 129 msec

dig aruba.it @8.8.8.8
Query time: 20 msec
```

nmap -sT -p 53 192.168.50.35

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-11-06 14:31 CET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.50.35
Host is up (0.0014s latency).
```

ping -c5 192.168.50.35

```
PING 192.168.50.35 (192.168.50.35) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.50.35: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.31 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.50.35: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.34 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.50.35: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.33 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.50.35: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=5.56 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.50.35: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.32 ms

--- 192.168.50.35 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.312/2.177/5.561/1.692 ms
```

This happens with all domains. Switching bind config with forwarders I've same problem: queries are slowes.

Is this correct a query time for a local DNS?

```
cat /etc/bind/named.conf.options

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

// uncomment these to switch to forwarders
//        forwarders {
//                8.8.8.8;
//                8.8.4.4;
//         };


        dnssec-validation auto;
        listen-on port 53 { localhost; 192.168.50.0/24; };
        allow-query { localhost; 192.168.50.0/24; };
        recursion yes;

};
```

Disabling IPv6 doesn't change anything.

Comment: On a bind server on a local VLAN, I get 2 ms response time. Can you edit your question and post ping and nmap tcp connect ping times?

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is caching. DNS records are cached in DNS servers (as well as cached in clients). Google DNS is a public DNS server used by too many users around the globe. So, there is good chance that the requested name has recently been resolved by Google DNS. This means better response time when compared to your local DNS server.

Another reason is the optimization and tuning done by Google. Such a public DNS server must be optimized to handle the traffic it receives.

By the way, you can verify the caching effect by repeating the DNS query to your server. You will get a much better response time from the second time (result has been cached).

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. Do you advice me about tuning cache ttl?

Comment: Tuning records TTL value may not help. It is just a hint (no enforcement) on how long a record is considered valid.

Comment: A last question: how you, in your lan have 2ms?

Comment: I did not say that! You can use Google DNS as forwarder to help improve your DNS speed.